# Testing the design of a page every time a new code is pushed

Tags: css, angularjs, testing

I  am looking for a testing framework to kind of test the front end and design of my application. I am building an angular application and we are using [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) for the end to end tests, however I was wondering how do we test the design and the actual layout.

For instance when my partner pushed code last week he broke the navigation menu barand we want to make sure we have automated test that makes sure that the css is not broken before we push it in to prod. I am open to all suggestions. I was wondering if protractor can be used for this or is there a a better tool?Protractor does give you ability to localte css elements by id etc but not sure if this is a smart approach.

Answer (score 1):

It might not provide everything you need, but BackstopJS seems to be capable of handling CSS breakage:

https://garris.github.io/BackstopJS/

Comment: Thank you for sharing, is there a standard framework that is used? For instance protractor is standard for e2e test on an angular app.